# C# PrintDocument - table / grid layout trouble

Tags: c#, printdocument

I'm trying to print out some data to a page in a table / grid format.
At the moment i have it working, but everything is drawn out manually.
Fairly hard-coded values for the width and height of each cell.

What I'm trying to do is turn it onto a more generic solution. Create some kind of object containing all the data and have it basically render itself.

The problem I am having is finding a way to determine the height of each cell, making sure it is big enough for the data contained within it.

What I have at the moment is something like:

```
protected override void OnPrintPage(PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    DrawPageHeader();

    List<ItemDTO> ItemsForPage = GetItemsToRenderOnThisPage();

    for (int i = 1; i < ItemsForPage.Count; i ++)
    {
        //Each column is rendered in this method. The X and Y start positions are passed, plus the width of the column.
        DrawColumn(g, ItemsForPage[0], column1X, totalWidth / ItemsForPage.Count, itemStartY);
    }
}

private int DrawColumnForItem(Graphics g, ItemDTO item, int startPoint, int columnWidth, int rowPosition)
{
    //Draw the vertical Lines
    g.DrawLine(linePen, lineLeft, rowPosition, lineLeft, lineHeight);
    g.DrawLine(linePen, lineRight, rowPosition, lineRight, lineHeight);
    g.DrawLine(linePen, startPoint - 2, rowPosition, startPoint - 2, lineHeight);

    // (85 characters max field) 
    g.DrawLine(linePen, lineLeft, rowPosition, lineRight, rowPosition);
    g.DrawString("Description", smallBoldFont, Brushes.Black, 3, ++rowPosition);
    g.DrawString(item.Desc, smallFont, Brushes.Black, new Rectangle(startPoint, rowPosition, columnWidth, rowIncrement * 2));
    rowPosition += rowIncrement;
    rowPosition += rowIncrement;

    //Details (250 characters max)
    g.DrawLine(linePen, lineLeft, rowPosition, lineRight, rowPosition);
    g.DrawString("Detailed Desc", smallBoldFont, Brushes.Black, 3, ++rowPosition);
    g.DrawString(item.DetailedDescription, smallFont, Brushes.Black, new Rectangle(startPoint, rowPosition, columnWidth, rowIncrement * 2));
    rowPosition += rowIncrement;
    rowPosition += rowIncrement;
    rowPosition += rowIncrement;

    //Gender (M or F)
    g.DrawLine(linePen, lineLeft, rowPosition, lineRight, rowPosition);
    g.DrawString("Gender", smallBoldFont, Brushes.Black, 3, ++rowPosition);
    g.DrawString(item.Gender.ToString(), smallFont, Brushes.Black, startPoint, rowPosition);
    rowPosition += rowIncrement;
}
```

You see the idea.
I'm drawing each line.
Then the text, then incrememnting the position of the row to move onto the next line.

So there are 3 fields above.
Each one has a different max size, and hence each one will potentially need a larger or smaller 'cell'.

So I gues what I really need is a method of finding how much space a given piece of text will take up.
g.MeasureString will give me the width, but not the height (if it wraps to multiple lines). So I dont know how many rows to give it.

Also an issue with it being so manually measured is every time I make a change I have to go through and start tweaking again to make sure everything lines up.

I'm going to be doing similar documents, so it would be great if mostly it could be automated.

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I know this is old, but that is no reason to have it hanging around without an answer.

You need to use the **GetHeight** or **MeasureString** method.  Either one  requires the font you wish to measure, so using your *smallFont* where it can be defined  (for example purposes)

```
smallFont = New Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Regular)
```

You can get the height by:

```
smallFont.GetHeight(g)
```

alternately

```
g.MeasureString("TestString", smallFont)
```